# Use CDI to load Beans dynamically - EJB3

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jndi, cdi

I am using EJB3 in my application and I want to know can I `inject` beans dynamically at runtime based on some parameter ?

Because I have a `@Local` interface which extends several beans which works in different manner. So at run time I want to load each bean depend on the logic.  So far I used usual `JNDI lookup` But I would like to do it with `@Inject`. Is there a way that I can inject the bean dynamically?

Here is my existing `lookup` code. I pass the bean name as `jndi` here and build the instance dynamically.

```
IService bean = (IService) initialContext.lookup(jndi+"Bean/local"); 
bean.initializeTimer(firstDate, period, request);
```

---

### UPDATE

I have three beans for the moment. 
 
first bean is SingleServiceBean

```
 @Stateless
 public class SingleServiceBean implements IService{

    @Override
    public void doSomething (){
     log.debug("inside do something");
    }

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SingleServiceBean.class.getName());
 }
```

Second bean is PeriodicService

```
 @Stateless
 public class PeriodicServiceBean implements IService{

    @Override
    public void doSomething (){
     log.debug("inside do something");
    }

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(PeriodicServiceBean.class.getName());
 }
```

Third bean

```
 @Stateless
 public class AsyncServiceBean implements IService{

    @Override
    public void doSomething (){
     log.debug("inside do something");
    }

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AsyncServiceBean.class.getName());
 }
```

---

### 2nd Update

Qualifier   :

```
 @Qualifier
 @Target({ TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
 @Retention(RUNTIME)
 @Documented
 public @interface Services {
   String type(); 

 }
```

AnnotationLiteral

```
 public class ServiceQualifier extends AnnotationLiteral<Services> implements Services{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6471734834552932687L;
private String type;

public String TypeQualifier(String t) {
      this.type = t;
      return type;
}

public String type() {
    return type;
}
 }
```

And new bean class like below

```
 @Services(type = "SingleService" )
 @Stateless
 public class SingleServiceBean implements IService{
 .....
 }
```

then I add the below lines in my bean caller class

```
 @Inject
private Instance<IService> iServiceInstance;

public void someMethod() {

// this line gives me error by red underline in .select(...)
IService service = iServiceInstance.select(new ServiceQualifier().TypeQualifier("SingleService")).get();
}
```

Error I get in eclipse : "The method select(Annotation...) in the type Instance is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: Method 'TypeQualifier' should return the ServiceQualifier instance because the parameter of .select(..) must be an annotation literal, not a String. So replace with 'return this;' and change the return type of this method and all will works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using local interfaces, you would need to use a qualifier in CDI (rather than JNDI location).  On your impl, do something like this:

```
@Local
@Stateless
@MyQualifier("someValue")
public class MyServiceOne implements IService {
    ...
}
```

Where `MyQualifier` could have any value - even the JNDI name.  Then when you want to resolve it, do this:

```
@Inject @Any
private Instance<IService> iServiceInstance;

...

IService service = iServiceInstance.select(new MyQualifierLiteral("someValue")).get();
```

`MyQualifierLiteral` here is an `AnnotationLiteral` that implements `MyQualifier`.  This is what it should look like:

```
import javax.enterprise.util.AnnotationLiteral;

public class MyQualifierLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<MyQualifier> implements MyQualifier {

    private final String value;

    public MyQualifierLiteral(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Qualifier and bit confused. I have updated my all three bean classes can you please elaborate more?

Comment: I'm not sure how else I could elaborate.  Maybe this site helps, if you're not clear on qualifiers: https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_161_java_ee_6

Comment: I update the code with your answer. see the 2nd update. I get an error "The method select(Annotation...) in the type Instance<IService> is not applicable for the arguments (String)". Not sure where I am wrong.

Comment: Can you please help me John? Where am I gone wrong?

Comment: I updated my answer with how to define an annotation literal.

Comment: For me the bean is null. I have doubt that I inject the EJB to a usual java class which is instantiated by my own implementation.

Comment: John Ament's answer helped me a great deal. One problem I ran into with John's answer is I did have to add the `@Any` annotation to the Injection point because as it points out [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.0.3.Final/en-US/html/injection.html#lookup) using `@Any` suppresses the default qualifier. Now I am getting back the correct objects using select. Without `@Any` the container wasn't able to resolve the bean. Hopefully this will help others.

Comment: Thanks @Hodglem added `@Any` to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are firstdate, period and request runtime args? If so, you can only inject some kind of factory that creates the bean based on those properties.

If those values are fix at deployment or at least configurable, you can go with a Producer.

```
@Produces
public IService getTimer() {
  IService bean = (IService) initialContext.lookup(jndi+"Bean/local"); 
  bean.initializeTimer(firstDate, period, request);
  return bean;
}
```

You will need to find a way to supply the configuration values. Check the Qualifier concept or use System.set/get properties to transport the values.

Comment: Sorry Jan, I want to use CDI here. So not context lookup anymore.

Comment: Ok. From your original post i assumed that you have remote ejbs to deal with.